# VBA Excel 2013 Copy / paste - ensuring paste is a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying data from one workbook/ sheet to another workbook / sheet, extract of code below, and the Range (I119,I65) copy/pastes fine. My problem is that the ProvId copy/ paste sometimes enters the 4 digit ID as expected but on other times it puts "Today's Date". The occasions when this happens is when the Cell D9 is a formula. How do I ensure that ProvId is always the value of D9, in excel the Value function would work.

```
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & excelfile, UpdateLinks:=False  'Open each upload excel file


 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Audit Grant Return").Range("I19,I65").Copy

 ProvId = Cell("D9")


 MsgBox ("Id" & ProvId)   'To see what is happening


 ActiveWorkbook.Close


 Workbooks("15-16 AGR Data Imported.xlsm").Sheets(1).Activate
 Sheets("Upload").Select

 ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, ActiveRow), Cells(2, ActiveRow)) = ProvId
 ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, ActiveRow), Cells(4, ActiveRow)).PasteSpecial

 ProvId = ""
 ActiveRow = ActiveRow + 1
```

This loops round picking up all the files to be uploaded and works fine except for this ProvId issue. FYI I have Dim ProvId As Text 'stores Provider Id from upload file

Comment: (a) Where is your `Cell` variable/function defined?  I.e. is it a `Dictionary`, or a function, or something else?  (b) If it is a typo due to your typing the code into the question rather than just pasting it, and it is meant to be `Cells`, it is an unqualified reference and therefore defaults to the active sheet.  So which sheet is the "active" one when you open the workbook?  Is it the one that you want to get the value from?

Comment: It is a typo.  The active sheet is 'Audit Grant Return'  and is where the Id Value should be obtained from, it works on some uploads but not all!

Comment: (a) So "Audit Grant Return" is the only sheet in the `path & excelfile` workbook?  Or is the workbook **always** saved with that sheet being the active one? (b) What is `Cell("D9")` a typo of??  It can't be `Cells("D9")` - that doesn't work.  Hopefully it is a typo of `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Audit Grant Return").Range("D9").Value`.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K for your comments, I have got it working now OK.